# leg doesn't move with bones

Tags: rigging

I'm new in blender.. when I'm trying to move my body every thing is move with bones expect the lower leg(R and L)
[image: like This]

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I did now......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your armature, go in *Edit* or *Pose* mode, select your bone, go in the *Properties panel > Bone* and enable the *Deform* option (it should be enabled by default):

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU! it works! thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

To me this looks like a missing vertex group or "empty weightpaint".

You should check your vertex group "Lower Leg.L" (I'm assuming this is also the bone which is moving your left leg?)

1. Select your model and go in **Edit Mode**.
2. **Select your vertex group** responsible moving the left leg. In your case it might be "Lower Leg.L".
3. Select that part of the mesh you want to move (it's enough to **select a single vertice** and press **Ctrl +L**, this way you select linked mesh parts).
4. In the vertex groups Tab hit **Assign**. This assigns the vertices to the selected vertex group. Make sure the vertex groups are named correct and according to your bones. Also check for accidentally written spacing, they are sometimes barely noticable.
5. If you go to **Weightpaint Mode**, that part of youre leg should appear red and follow your "Lower Leg.L". This means, the bone has 100% influence on the motion of this part of the mesh.

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your time.